ISO, Rethink Robotics Sawyer OS image
I recently acquired a Rethink Robotics Sawyer Robotic Arm and it appears that the SSD's are bad. The boot sector seems to be intact as it prints on the screen "Booting Intera in .." but never comes to life and when I USB attach the HD to another computer it is not even recognized as a drive. It appears that I can download any of the 5.x updates, but I am unable to find and ISO that could help me init a new drive. If someone could point me to a download link or maybe dd a copy off another Sawyer, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you
John
